# Bootstrap datepicker custom format saving to DATE MySQL

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a registration form for a website which uses bootstrap datepicker module to handle "birthday" date in a format dd.mm.yyyy.

Input:

```
<input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker" required />
```

JS:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({    
   format: "dd.mm.yyyy",    
   weekStart: 1,    
   autoclose: true  
});
```

When a user submits the form, this is how I get the birthday

```
$user->birthday=$_POST['birthday'];
```

and in the user creation class, I will sanitize the input with:

```
$this->birthday=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->birthday));
```

Now, I want to save this into a MySQL table, and "birthday" column is formatted as DATE, so it has to have the format of Y-m-d. To do this, I tried to convert the date like so:

```
//since I get a string, first convert it to time, create a date from it and format it to Y-m-d and then bind it to the birthday parameter.
$birthday_converted = date_format(date_create(strtotime($this->birthday)),"Y-m-d");
$stmt->bindParam(':birthday', $this->birthday_converted);
```

When I do this, I get an error saying this:

**Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, integer given**

even though, the date will be written into the database, but incorrectly. For example, if the date picked is 16.03.**2020** (March 16th), in DB I will get **2016**-03-20

Comment: How about using [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) ? Fiddle [test here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7xgdfnnVYz6aUCn33KLD17/0)

Comment: but as I see, this is something to use when reading from a database, while I'm looking for something to write a date into a DB

Comment: It can use to write/insert/update .. refer [this example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7xgdfnnVYz6aUCn33KLD17/2)

Comment: Thanks! However, I solved it like this: $this->birthday=date_format(date_create(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->birthday))),"Y-m-d");

Answer (score 1):

I actually just added "the conversion" into the "sanitization" part:

```
$this->birthday=date_format(date_create(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->birthday))),"Y-m-d");
```

And then I have a clean birthday ready for binding to a parameter.